# React Native pass data into modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-modal

I'm still new in react native and programming, and i am trying to pass items from my flat list into a modal. What i'm about to pass is the icon, status, and description. How am i supposed to do that?

this is my flatlist

```js
buildPanel(index, item) {
    let panel = [];
    let keys = DBkeys['Requests'].MyRequest;
    
    let status = item[keys['status']];
    panel.push(<View style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 0, bottom: 0, padding: normalize(5), alignItems: 'center' }} key={'status'}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleShowModal}>
        <Icon name={img.itemStatus[status].name} type={img.itemStatus[status].type} color={img.itemStatus[status].color} size={normalize(38)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>);

    return panel;
    }
    
    <View style={[styles.panelContainer, status === 'success' ? {} : { backgroundColor: color.white }]}>
              <FlatList
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                progressViewOffset={-10}
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
                onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y === 0 ? this.onRefresh() : null}
                data={content}
                renderItem={({ item }) => item}
                keyExtractor={(item, key) => key.toString()}
                 />
            </View>
            <IconModal visible={this.state.modalVisible} close={this.handleDismissModal}/>
```

and this is my IconModal.js

```js
const IconModal = (props) => {

    return(
        <Modal 
            isVisible={props.visible}
            onBackdropPress={props.close}
        >
            <View style={styles.dialogBox}> 
                <View style={styles.icon}>
                    <Icon name='open-book' type='entypo' color='#ffb732' size={normalize(70)} />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.text}>
                    <Text style={styles.status}>Status</Text>
                    <Text>Desc</Text>
                </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.close}>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>GOT IT</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>   
            </View>
            
        </Modal>
    )
}

IconModal.propTypes ={
    visible: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    close: PropTypes.func,
}
```

Answer (score 5):

from the `renderItem` of your `FlatList`,

You must be clicking somewhere to open modal,

when you click store that whole single item in state variable,

like, if you're using `TouchableOpacity` then

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.passDataToModal}/>
...
...
passDataToModal=(item)=>{
 this.setState({modalData:item},()=>{
   //you can open modal here
});
}
```

and in your modal component,

you can pass data with prop.

```
<IconModal modalData={this.state.modalData} visible={this.state.modalVisible} close={this.handleDismissModal}/>
```

and you can use these data in `IconModal` as `this.props.modalData`.

If there is more data then you can always add another prop.

Comment: could you give me more example, i still don't get it

Answer (score 3):

Define the following Hooks in your function Component.

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
const [modalData, setModalData] = useState([]);
const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] =  useState('');
```

Now Trigger the function which opens the Modal, while simultaneously passing data into it.

```
<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="skyblue" onPress={() => { openSettingsModal(title,settings) } }>
    Open Modal
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Here is the function code -

```
const openSettingsModal = (title,settings) => {
    setModalTitle(title);
    setModalData(settings);
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
}
```

And finally a snippet of the Modal Code.

```
<Modal animationType="none" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible} >
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
        <Text> { modalTitle }</Text>
        <Text> { modalData }</Text>
    </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: This implementation give us this warning "Warning: Cannot update a component (`%s`) while rendering a different component (`%s`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `%s`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render%s,"

Answer (score 0):

For example:

class Container extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: false,
            activeItemName: '', //state property to hold item name
            activeItemId: null, //state property to hold item id
        }
    }

```
openModalWithItem(item) {
    this.setState({
        modalVisible: true,
        activeItemName: item.name,
        activeItemId: item.id
    })
}

render() {

    let buttonList = this.props.item.map(item => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.openModalWithItem(item) }}>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    });

    return (
        <View>
            {/* Example Modal Component */}
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.openDeleteModal}
                itemId={this.state.activeItemId}
                itemName={this.state.activeItemName} />
            {buttonList}
        </View>
    )
}
```

}